# Table v.s., node

Tags: nodes, theming

I am migrating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and have the opportunity to restructure data.

Assume storage of contacts: A node was created of type contact, but information was stored, such as birthday, in other fields.  I didn't design it and don't know why another field wasn't added to the node via CCK.

Nonetheless, is there any reason from a performance standpoint to create a table called "contact" and store all relent information there (e.g., is there performance overhead in using the "node" structure v.s., a simple table - and yes, I know a node is a table).

The database engine in use is MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is definitely a performance overhead to dealing with your content in Drupal nodes / cck vs using a simple table, assuming you are keeping all of your contacts data in that one table. The performance overhead comes from the abstraction built into the CCK system that requires complex SQL queries to construct your data record from multiple tables (ex. fields, input formats, other modules).

For the most part, you probably want to use CCK because it makes it easier to manipulate this data and add new fields and it exposes your data to dozens of other modules. If this performance hit is an issue you can counteract it by using caching at either the mysql, php, apache, or drupal layer. Otherwise, you can keep your data in a simple (non-drupal) table and expose it to views and other modules by using the Data module.

And Last but Not least, you can run your own storage strategy for a node it the standard fields approach is not enough.

Comment: Well, CCK isn't an option in Drupal 7 because it is, for the most part, built into core (although, there is dev version available).
There must be some benefit that outweighs the multiple fetch operations required to get the contents of a node. Almost every scrap of useful data from a node is stored in a separate table. 
For one, it is fairly obvious that there are "build in" structures that support node management that otherwise would have to be re-invented.